# wicket I'm using three panels, but only one is displayed at a time, when the third panel is added to the code the second never appears

Tags: bootstrap-modal, wicket, panels

I have a Modal class, when this modal is opened, it shows a panel asking the user if the user wants to proceed with the operation. If the user selects Yes the request is sent to the DB, which takes some time, during this time the first panel should be replaced by the second (which displays a spinner). This indeed happens if we do not use the third panel. Although I want to replace the second panel by the third panel in order to inform the user if the operation was successful or not (which depends of the message object,if it is null or have an error message).

So when I use addNewPanel(panel3, target) I never see panel2. I put a thread.sleep(5000) instruction after addNewPanel(panel2, target) and even so, this panel didn't appeared, I only get the initial and panel3 in the end.
If I do not use panel3 I see panel2.

Does anyone have an idea why is this happening?

Below I have the code of the Modal class

```
  public class DetailsModal2 extends Modal<IModel<UserDomain>>{

  @SpringBean
  private IService service;
  private  BootstrapAjaxLink<String> noButton;
  private ResponseMessage message;
  private ProcessingPanel panel2;
  private AlertPanel panel3;
  private Panel replacedPanel;

  public DetailsModal2(String id, IModel<UserDomain> model){
         super(id);

         replacedPanel = new AreYouSure("replacedPanel");
         replacedPanel.setOutputMarkupId(true);
         add(replacedPanel);

         panel2 = new ProcessingPanel("replacedPanel");
         panel3 = new AlertPanel("replacedPanel");


         addButton(new BootstrapAjaxLink<String>("button", null, Buttons.Type.Warning, new ResourceModel("details")){

           private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


           @Override
           public void onClick(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

               //I was expecting to see this panel
               addNewPanel(panel2,target);

               // this puts this button invisible
               this.setVisible(false);
               target.add(this);
               //this changes the label of the No button to Close
               noButton.setLabel(Model.of("Close"));
               target.add(noButton);

               if(!service.retrieveData())
                 {

                     message = service.addUser("X");
                    if(message == null){
                        panel3.updateClassAndText(true);
                        addNewPanel(panel3,target);
                }
                else {
                    panel3.updateClassAndText(false);
                    addNewPanel(panel3,target);
                    System.out.println(""+ message.getError());
                }
            }//close if

            else if(service.retrieveData())
            {       
                message = service.removeUser("X");
                if(message == null){
                    panel3.updateClassAndText(true);
                    addNewPanel(panel3,target);
                }
                else{
                    panel3.updateClassAndText(false);
                    addNewPanel(panel3,target);
                    System.out.println(""+ message.getError()); 
                }
            }

        else{ 
            System.out.println("It was not possible to access the db");
        }
            }

        }
    });

      noButton = new BootstrapAjaxLink<String>("button", null, Buttons.Type.Primary){
          private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Override
        public void onClick(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
            close(target);      
        }
    }.setLabel(Model.of("No"));
    addButton(noButton);

 }      
public void addNewPanel(Panel addpanel, AjaxRequestTarget target ){
    Panel newPanel = null;
    newPanel = addpanel;
    newPanel.setOutputMarkupId(true);
    replacedPanel.replaceWith(newPanel);
    target.add(newPanel);   
 }
 }//close class
```

HTML

```
 <wicket:extend>    
     <div><span wicket:id="replacedPanel"> </span></div>
 </wicket:extend>
```

Comment: This is happening because of the way the http get works. The client sends a request to the server and the server responds with a response. When you click the AjaxLink the browser sends a request to your server and wicket then executes the whole onclick method before sending the response. You only ever get the response after the onClick method was fully executed so you cannot add " intermediate result" panels that get shown in the middle of executing the onClick method and then later replaced.

Comment: As for a possible solution you could check out wicket atmosphere framework implementation which offers you a way to send push requests from the server to the client: http://examples7x.wicket.apache.org/atmosphere/.

Answer (score 0):

Wicket atmosphere is deprecated from wicket 8 and will not be supported anymore, so do not use it ..